# ::-webkit-scrollbar-button with content

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I've tried to design the webkit scrollbar like Visual Studio.

**Example:**

[image: Original Visual Studio Scrollbar]

My question is, how i can set the `::-webkit-scrollbar-button` like the example?

Here is my Code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 10px;
    content: "▲";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

**Output:**
[image: My Scrollbar]

It is possible to use `content: "";` property to set an UTF-Character like ▲ or ▼ ?
Why it would'nt display?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzv4gphy/)

Answer (score 2):

The `content: ""` does not seem to work with the scrollbar. I also tried with the `content: "\25B2"`but still does not work.

Maybe you can use a background image like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilsonalberto/hLk2zbfp/)